# Queue that is consuming objects of the same interface and executing work in lock

Tags: java, android, multithreading, collections, queue

community!

I need to implement some kind of Queue which will take objects of one interface, let's call this interface **Command** and execute their work in sequence.

For example, I have interface **Command** like this

```
public interface Command {

    public void execute();

}
```

And I have class, that implements this interface

```
public class BasicCommand implements Command {
    private int operationId;

    public BasicCommand(int operationId) {
        this.operationId = operationId;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        Log.d("BasicCommand", "Id: " + operationId);
    }
}
```

I need a Queue that will execute this commands in sequence and will call their `execute()` method.

I will add more and more classes that will implement Command in future.

Are there similar things already implemented in Android or could anyone provide some code snippets?

Comment: You could submit these commands to a `ExecutorService` instance. It will execute them. The command need to implement a `Runnable` interface and have the `run()` method call the `execute()` method. Does that make sense?

Comment: A `Queue` does not execute anything, a `Queue` merely *queues* the objects for access in the order they are added to the queue.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, I didn't said that I need a Queue object, I am sorry for not transparent description.
I need data structure, that is basically a blocking Queue that executes some work.

Comment: @nitnamby, could it extend Tread instead?

Comment: @ОлегМісько it could extend a `Thread`, but  implementing a `Runnable` is considered better.

Comment: A [`java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) does almost exactly what you want.  The only difference is, what you call `execute()`, it calls `submit()`, and what you call `Command`, it calls `Callable.`  Only the names are different.

Comment: P.S., not sure what you mean by "execute work in lock," but if you want any kind of mutual exclusion between the _tasks_ (i.e., `Callable`s) that you submit to the executor and any other threads, then you will have to provide that yourself.

Comment: @jameslarge, I meant a basic monitor or semaphore. 
Btw, thank you for a suggestion. I will check it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed you could use a `ExecutorService` instance and submit commands as tasks to it. A sample implementation below.

```
public class BasicCommand implements Command, Callable<Integer>{

private int operationId;

public BasicCommand(int operationId) {
    this.operationId = operationId;
}

public Integer call(){
    this.execute();
    return operationId;
}

@Override
public void execute() {
    //Log.d("BasicCommand", "Id: " + operationId);
    System.out.println("hello executing command" + operationId);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    ExecutorService exceutorService= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    exceutorService.submit(new BasicCommand(1));
    Future future =exceutorService.submit(new BasicCommand(2));
    System.out.println("result:" +future.get());

}
```

Comment: @user6690200 There is only a single thread executing the tasks, it is not in parallel.

Comment: I do not need this tasks to be executed in parallel, but in sequence, as I've added them. That why I used term 'Queue' in my question.

I basically add some objects (let's assume they implement Runnable) and they execute their work one-by-one.

If one starts to work - all others wait.

Comment: It is not executed in parallel as there is only one thread. Tasks are added to A `BlockingQueue` implementation and executed sequentially by the `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Yeah, when you create it by `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, there is only one working thread.

Comment: @nitnamby, this is what I need.

Comment: @nitnamby, yes, but one more question. When we submit a task to ExecutorService it returns us Future<?> object. How can I use it to retrieve basic callback from my Command, for example, the id of the command that is incremented in some dummy method (this example is just to easy show)

Comment: @ОлегМісько `Future` represents the result of an asynchronous computation of the task. 'get()' would return the result of it and is a blocking call. You could implement a 'Callable' instand of 'Runnable' if it needs to return something. I have just updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to execute these commands in sequence order, I would suggest to use Producer-Consumer pattern, you can use two threads and a blocking queue to achieve this.

Basiclly, the producer will try to put new `Command` in the queue, while the consumer will try to take them out. The blocking queue will handle the synchronization issues between the producer and consumer.

Example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BlockingQueue<Command> commands = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
        new Thread(new Consumer(commands)).start();
        new Thread(new Producer(commands)).start();
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    BlockingQueue<Command> commands;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Command> commands) {
        this.commands = commands;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Command command;
        try {
            while ((command = commands.take()) != null) {
                command.execute();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    BlockingQueue<Command> commands;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Command> commands) {
        this.commands = commands;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                commands.put(new Command() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute() {
                        System.out.println("Command");
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```